# Extract date and time in R to include in filename

Tags: r

How do include date and time in the filename modifying the below code.

```
 write.csv(listOfDataFrames1, file = "percent.csv")
```

Something like percent-date-time.

Are there functions in r that can directly read the system date and time or any way to connect to the web in R to gather such information.

Comment: Try `Sys.time()`, `paste`

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do that because `file.info("percent.csv")` will give you lots of information about a file, including three different times.  But you could also use `sprintf("percent%s.csv", Sys.Date())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
  str1 <- 'percent.csv'
  paste0(sub('\\..*', '', str1), format(Sys.time(),'_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'), '.csv')
  #[1] "percent_20141224_132055.csv"
```

I used the above code which works great:

```
write.csv(listOfDataFrames1, file = paste0(sub('\\..*', ' ', str1), format(Sys.time(),'%d_%m__%H_%M'), '.csv'))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem quite clear. Could I add any symbol in between directly                                          write.csv(listOfDataFrames1, file paste("percent",Sys.time(),".csv") doesn't work due to - symbol

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia  If you want some `delimiter`, `_` would be better to separate the `percent` , `date` and `time`  Here, I used `format` because the `Sys.time()` has some `space` which would create some problems.